# clang-format vs array initialization

Tags: c, clang-format

I have a set of arrays initialization. A simplified version is as follows:

```
/* intentionally badly formatted */
void static const AdcDesc_t fastAnalogFeed[] =
{
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN1, 0),
      DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN2, 0),
     DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN3, 0),
      DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN4, 0),
   DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN7, 0),
       DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN8, 0),
  DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN9, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN10, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN11, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN12, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN13, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN14, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN15, 0),
};
```

my `.clang-format` is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/reufkz184mbn1nn/.clang-format?dl=0)

Trying to format the file above I get:

```
void static const AdcDesc_t fastAnalogFeed[] = {
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN1, 0),  DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN2, 0),  DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN3, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN4, 0),  DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN7, 0),  DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN8, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN9, 0),  DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN10, 0), DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN11, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN12, 0), DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN13, 0), DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN14, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN15, 0),
};
```

Instead I would like to achieve something like this:

```
void static const AdcDesc_t fastAnalogFeed[] =
{
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN1, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN2, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN3, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN4, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN7, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN8, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN9, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN10, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN11, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN12, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN13, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN14, 0),
    DECL_ADC_CH_SIMPLE(ADC2_IN15, 0),
};
```

What's wrong with my `.clang-format` file and how should I edit it?

Answer (score 2):

You can either turn your clang-format off before and after and maintain the formatting by yourself (`// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on`) or add comments after each entry. The comments will keep the array entries from being packed.